# Como trocar ponto por virgula em java e no tipo BigDecimal?

Tags: java

Sou iniciante em java e estou com dúvida no tipo `BigDecimal`, pois ele aceita valores com pontos e não com virgulas. Estou desenvolvendo um software para videolocadora e quero salvar o valor da minha categoria de filme com virgula e não com ponto:

```
private void btnSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    BigDecimal valor = new BigDecimal(0);

    if (!cmpValor.getText().equals("")) {  
        valor = new BigDecimal(cmpValor.getText());  
    }  
    if(cmpDescricao != null) {
        categoriaController.salvar(cmpDescricao.getText(), valor);
    }
}
```

Quando digito o valor da categoria com vírgula, minha aplicação gera erro:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:494)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:383)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:806)
    at view.VideoCategoria.btnSalvarActionPerformed(VideoCategoria.java:206)
    at view.VideoCategoria.access$000(VideoCategoria.java:20)
    at view.VideoCategoria$1.actionPerformed(VideoCategoria.java:66)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Gostaria de saber se há um meio de ele aceitar números digitados com vírgula!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode alterar a virgula por ponto através do código, assim, no front-end isso ficará transparante.

## Exemplo

```
 valor = new BigDecimal(cmpValor.getText().replace(",",".");
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui! Valeu e obrigado!

Comment: @IgorContini, por favor, marque como resposta para que possa ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida.